Filling a figure created with arc
How can I fill out this figure? I am trying hard to copy this picture.

Here my code:
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[step=1cm,black,very thin] (0,0) grid (3,3);
  \coordinate (A) at (2,3);
  \coordinate (B) at (2,4);
  \coordinate (C) at (3,4);
  \coordinate (D) at (3,3); 
  \draw (D) arc[start angle=0, end angle=-90, radius=3];
  \draw (D) arc[start angle=0, end angle=-90, radius=2];
  \coordinate (A) at (2,2);
  \coordinate (B) at (2,3);
  \coordinate (C) at (3,3);
  \coordinate (D) at (3,2); 
  \draw (A) arc[start angle=90, end angle=180, radius=2];
  \draw (A) arc[start angle=90, end angle=180, radius=1];
\end{tikzpicture}


Welcome to TeX.SE!

A simple solution
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[step=1cm,black,very thin] (0,0) grid (3,3);
    \draw[fill=red, fill opacity=0.7] (0,0) arc[start angle=-90, end angle=0, radius=3]
        arc[start angle=0, end angle=-90, radius=2]
        arc[start angle=180, end angle=90, radius=1]
        arc[start angle=90, end angle=180, radius=2] -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


